# Why doesn't my If-Else block work the way it should?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to swift and using firebase, I'm making a simple application that let's user input a cellular prefix number and displays what cellular network is that number.

I'M having a hard problems with the if-else part. Whenever I add the else part, the label always displays "Missing" but whenever I print the snapshot.key and snapshot.value, I get the correct result in the console. When I remove the else part, it works. I'm really having a hard time figuring out the answer. Thanks in advance! Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

let loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton = {
    let button = FBSDKLoginButton()
    button.readPermissions = ["email"]
    return button
}()

@IBOutlet weak var numField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var answerField: UILabel!

@IBAction func enterButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    matchNumber()
}

func matchNumber(){

    let number: String = numField.text!
    let numRef = Firebase(url: "https://npi2.firebaseio.com/num_details")
    numRef.queryOrderedByKey().observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
        let network = snapshot.value as! String!
            if snapshot.key ==  self.numField.text! {
                self.answerField.text = network

            }
            else {
                self.answerField.text = "Missing"
            }

    })

    }
```

Comment: There is no `else` in the code you posted. Please narrow down posted code to just the part relevant to the issue.

Comment: My bad sorry. I already edited it. Thank you

Comment: what do you get when you print the `snapshot.key` and `self.numField.text!` are they the same? you mentioned snapshot key and value but thats not what you are testing for

Comment: Log String(snapshot.key ==  self.numField.text!) and see what comes out in the console.

Comment: i have a feeling the block that is executing the if-else, is happening more than once, and it sets the `self.answerField.text` one time, then another its hitting the else statement, which is why it would work without the else statement because its not being overridden. just a guess

Comment: @asdf Did my answer fix your issue ?

Comment: yes thank you very much @Coder1000 :)

Comment: @asdf Happy to help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what is happening.

---

**EXPLANATION:**

1) You make your request to Firebase.

2) The request is asynch, so the code keeps running.

3) The request is not done yet, therefore the `else` statement is executed because  the value is not yet returned (checks for initial state).

4) When you remove the `else`, the code executes the `if` because there is nothing else to execute until the request is done (initial state is checked but there is no code to execute for it, then Firebase checks again because there is a data change and the `if` statement is executed).

---

**REFERENCE:**

From the FIREBASE DOCUMENTATION (that you should have read before coming here :P)

"Firebase data is retrieved by attaching an asynchronous listener to a database reference. The listener will be triggered **once for the initial state** of the data **and again anytime the data changes**. This document will cover the basics of retrieving data, how data is ordered, and how to perform simple queries on data in your Firebase database."

https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html

---

**SOLUTION:**

Use the completion handler. It's made for that. Don't use `else` statements inside your request like that. That's not how you use Firebase.